# Can I use an oem windows 8 key to activate windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8 core oem key & I obtained an windows 8.1 iso from windows 8 upgrade site using a retail key. (Because the setup doesn't accept oem keys) After i do a clean installation with a generic key will I be able to activate using my oem key? That downloadable iso is a retail iso version :(

Comment: If you are eligible to use the Windows Store to install the update then your OEM Windows 8 license can be used to activate a Windows 8.1 installation.  You should be aware that the setup doesn't accept any Windows 8 keys.

Comment: yh, I was more worried about the activation. And what I meant was, I wasn't allowed to download the iso with my OEM key. Instead I had to use a retail key which I found on a Google search :) Which makes me afraid to install. Anyway the update is visible on windows store. So I'll try a clean install. thanks :)

Comment: Your key will be able to be activated based on the fact after you apply the update through the Windows Store it would still have to be activated.

Comment: I got my windows 8 (preinstalled, activated) computer last Wednesday, applied all the updates, then upgraded the next day to 8.1 using the Windows Store.  So, one would have assumed that I was eligible.  Yet, the following day I got a persistent popup window saying that my copy of Windows needed to be activated.  After trying a number of things, I contacted Microsoft support which told me that they could not help me. Windows *technical* support told me that it should have been valid.  I had to use a recovery CD to reinstalled 8 as the partition on which 8 was "saved" could not be found.

Comment: Activation worked fine with the OEM key. Thanks @Ramhound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem. I was able activate using my windows 8 OEM key after a clean installation with windows 8.1 ISO.