# How to use Windows8 OEM product key to activate Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, oem

Recently I downgraded my  Windows 8 Core Single Language Edition OEM PC to Windows 7 and now I need to upgrade my PC to 8.1 I've my Windows 8 Core Single Language Edition product key. I didn't activated my windows 7 because I don't have a valid key and unfortunately I don't have the Windows 8 OEM installation disc. So if I reinstall my pc with windows 8.1 is there anyway to activate it using my Windows 8 Core Single Language Edition OEM   key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 fresh install with Windows 8 licence](http://superuser.com/questions/661261/windows-8-1-fresh-install-with-windows-8-licence), [Can I use an oem windows 8 key to activate windows 8.1?](http://superuser.com/questions/665215/can-i-use-an-oem-windows-8-key-to-activate-windows-8-1)

Comment: Activate sure; Provided its installed already; just activate it;  What license key did you use to install Windows 8.1 since the 8.0 license key you do have didn't work?